# Jquery : Mask does not erase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am not able to type anything into a textbox field that put date mask he will not let me delete or type over he always gets 11/11/1111

The following are the codes that put:

All I'm importing:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JavascriptInsano.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/funcao_validate_data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On that same page has the Input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DataInicio, "Data de Início", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataInicio, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Now follows the javascript that makes the function:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#DataInicio").mask("11/11/1111",{placeholder:" "});
});

jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#DataTermino").mask("11/11/1111");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By your lib [jquery.maskedinput](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)(I assume you use it by the included js filename.), I believe it tells you to put `9` instead of `1`'s to format. And use `placeHolder` to indicate user the format.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $("#dateTest").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="dateTest" />
```